# Robotium with parameter

Tags: android, robotium

Is there any way from which i can run a single test case multiple times with different data in robotium tesing of an android application.
Just like parameterized juint testing.

```
public class UserTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

public UserTest() {
        super(TestActivity.class);
    }       

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // setUp() is run before a test case is started.

        // This is where the solo object is created.
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

public void testUserData1() throws Exception {

        // UserBean
        Bean bean = setUp.get(0);
        dataTest(bean);

    }



    public void testUserData2() throws Exception {

        // UserBean
        Bean bean = setUp.get(1);
        dataTest(bean);

    }
public void dataTest(Bean bean) {
        Log.e("testAddNote userbean", bean.toString());

        // Login
        solo.enterText(0, bean.getUserName());
        solo.enterText(1, bean.getPassWord());
        solo.clickOnButton(0);
}
```

this the way currently i am running test cases is there a way by which dataTest(Bean) can be executed multiple times with setUp elements as parameters.Means i have to call single method multiple times with different parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I just notice that this only works if you are using https://code.google.com/p/zohhak/

In that case you can do:

```
@TestWith({ 
           “2,  true”, 
           “6,  false”,
           “19, true” 
})
public void testPrimeNumberValidator(int number, boolean isPrime) { 
assertThat(… 
}
```